# How to solve azure devop api Object Moved result in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-devops-rest-api

When i have changed my blob status, I trying Azure DevOps Pipeline run using DevOps api in python.(so.. my code form is azure function's blob trigger form)

```
import logging

import http.client
import mimetypes

import azure.functions as func

from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint

def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
    logging.info(f"start connect devops")
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("dev.azure.com")
    body = "{\"previewRun\":false,\"stageToSkip=\": [],\"resources\": [], \"templateParameters\": [], \"variables\": []}"

    headers = {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Basic {Personal Access Token [String]}'
    }

    logging.info(f"try connect devops")
    conn.request("POST", "/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1", body, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    logging.info(res.msg)
    data = res.read()
    logging.info(f"%s", data.decode("utf-8"))
    logging.info(f"finish connect devops")
```

I got this result.

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://spsprodea2.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=dev.azure.com&amp;reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2Fgusrbs82mlops%2Ftestpipelinecall............">here</a>.</h2>
 </body></html>
```

'Authorization' : 'Basic {Personal Access Token [String]}'
: i used my account's Personal Access token in Azure Devops

Could you tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Offical Doc**

[Use personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat)

## You should convert your PAT (Personal Access Token) to base64 format.

> 'Authorization' : 'Basic {Personal Access Token [String]}'

**Code Like below.**

```
pat='lr***zcailq';
message_bytes = pat.encode('ascii')
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
base64_pat = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
url='https://dev.azure.com/jasonp2deploy/deployappwithvirtualapp/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0'
body = "{\"previewRun\":false,\"stageToSkip=\": [],\"resources\": [], \"templateParameters\": [], \"variables\": []}"
headers = {
    'Authorization' : 'Basic '+base64_pat
}
r = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank for your Answer. Mr. Pan.
When convert PAT used base53. it worked.
but... stuck again.

`/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1`
i thought this link's means 'Running pipeline' 
but my pipeline doesn't run. 
Do you know Why??

Comment: @박현균 Pls try other apis, make sure your code is right. Maybe there are some errors in this api(`/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipeline}/runs`). You need to confirm it.