# Azure devops rest api bearer token

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops

i have some problems trying to use a bearer token when calling a rest api.

I tried two methods with the same result:

## Method 1

I created an app registration in the azure portal, and gave it permissions to use devops api with user impersonation.

## Method 2

I created an app in https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/ and gave it project/teams management permission.

## Code

For my code, i used this (works when i use PAT to authenticate)

```
import requests
ADOtoken = 'obtained by microsoft example'
org = 'myorg'
projectName = 'test'
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {ADOtoken}"}
requesturl = f"https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
data  = {
                "name": projectName,
                "description": "description is requred",
                "capabilities": {
                    "versioncontrol": {
                    "sourceControlType": "Git"
                    },
                    "processTemplate": {
                    "templateTypeId": "6b724908-ef14-45cf-84f8-768b5384da45"
                    }
                }
            }
r = requests.post(requesturl, json = data, headers=headers)
```

## Getting the token

I get the token by using this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-webapp

I changed the scope to ['https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation']

## expected result

I expected to get an error to debug, or the project to be created

## actual result

I get a 203 (redirect) and content is the azure devops login site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Generate bearer token to invoke devops api, it works for me.

**Add api permission on portal.**

[image]

**My test code:**

```
import requests
import json

# get beartoken
beartoken=''

client_id = '<your_clientid>'
client_secret = '<your_secret>'
aadTenantDomain='<your_aadTenantDomain_like_microsoft.onmicrosoft.com>'
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+aadTenantDomain+'/oauth2/token'
token_data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'resource':'https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/',
}
token_r = requests.get(token_url, data=token_data)
d = json.loads(token_r.text)
beartoken= d['access_token']
print(beartoken)

# request devops api for test

url='https://dev.azure.com/jasonp2deploy/deployappwithvirtualapp/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0'
body = "{\"previewRun\":false,\"stageToSkip=\": [],\"resources\": [], \"templateParameters\": [], \"variables\": []}"

headers = {
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+beartoken
}

r = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

**My test result:**

[image]

## Method 2

If you also want to use pat, you  can refer my answer in below post.

**[How to solve azure devop api Object Moved result in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66592742/how-to-solve-azure-devop-api-object-moved-result-in-python/66595842#66595842)**

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method, the token is created but then the API returns a 203 error. The doc indicates that it is not supported. Did you configure anything else in azure devops? connected to a corporate organization.

The Azure DevOps API doesn't support non-interactive service access via service principals yet, although it is on the roadmap. If you need to call the Azure DevOps API from a non-interactive application (where an end user cannot authenticate interactively, such as a background job), it should use a personal access token (PAT)

Q: Why can't one of my service accounts access the Azure DevOps REST API?
A: Your service account may not have "materialized." Since signing in isn't possible with a service account that doesn't have interactive signing in permissions, check out this work-around.

src: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops